# Package doclicense error for version 2.0

Tags: licensing, doclicense

I want to print CC text and logo in bottom of first page of my latex cls template but it returns error for version 2.0. (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/) or (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
type={CC},
modifier={by-nd},
version={2.0},
]{doclicense}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \footnotetext{\doclicenseThis}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Error: `Package doclicense Error: License long name not defined. \doclicense@set`

**Update:** part of package that is related to the above error: (I have provided all required stuffs `type`, `modifier` and `version` (I don't know what `versionUsed` is!))

```
\ifcsdef{doclicense@lang@lic@\doclicense@type%
      @\doclicense@modifier @\doclicense@versionUsed}{}{%

      \PackageError{doclicense}{License long name not defined}{%
        Please check the manual of doclicense
        to see what you can do about it.%
      }%
    }
```

Comment: there is no provision for version 2.0 in the code, with version={3.0} or 4.0 it compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the 2.0 version of the license is not included in the package. You can add it youself by copying a `\namedef` line from one of the `.ldf` files provided with the package. Note that this definition should be added *before* loading the package. Note also that this of course does not add the full text, so commands like `\doclicenseFullText` will not work. However, the text of the link and the link itself printed by `\doclicenseThis` will work properly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{doclicense@lang@lic@CC@by-nd@2.0}{Attribution-NoDerivs 2.0 Generic}%
\makeatother
\usepackage[
type={CC},
modifier={by-nd},
version={2.0},
]{doclicense}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \footnotetext{\doclicenseThis}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Result, with a tooltip showing the link target:

[image]